# Parameters not being passed in POST method REST Java

Tags: java, rest, http, content-type

So, i am developing a web service where when i call api/update action on form submit, two of my inputs from my jsp, "data" and "id" are supposed to pass, on which i want to perform operations in the POST method block.

here is the form calling the method:

```
<form id="myForm" action="api/update" method="post">
id: <input type="text" id="id" name="id">
<br/>
<textarea id="data" name="data" rows="30" cols="100" placeholder="Empty File"></textarea>   
<br/>   
<button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the REST code:

```
@Path("update")
public class UpdateResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public UpdateResource() {
    }

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @POST
    public void putHtml() {
        String data = request.getParameter("data");
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        System.out.println(id);   //<---- line1
        System.out.println(data); //<---- line2
        //further operations
    }
}
```

The problem is that line1 and line2 gives null as output, means somehow data is not being passed. Am i doing something wrong?

Here is the Header file captured from network tab of chrome browser:
[image: Request Header has the data. underlined with red]

Comment: where is the end tag for your html form? run your test in chrome with the developer tools open on the 'network' tab and confirm that the data is actually being sent to the server.

Comment: end tag wasn't somehow being shown in question. corrected. and data is being sent. i verified from the network tab.

Comment: @KyleM data is being sent. attached image

Comment: Use `@FormParam` instead of trying to get the parameters from the HttpServletRequest. i.e `putHtml(@FormParam("id") String id)`

Comment: @peeskillet it worked. can you post it as an answer, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to get the parameters from the `HttpServletRequest`, use [`@FormParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html)

```
@POST
public void putHtml(@FormParam("id") String id,
                    @FormParam("data") String data) {
}
```

The reason is that the entity body is already being read, resulting in the parameters being empty in the `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: Your answer appears to be correct but do you have any source on what you mean by "it's already being read resulting in the parameters being empty"? Normally, attributes can be read any number of times from a request so long as they are not overwritten or removed.

Comment: @KyleM Have a look at the [last paragraph in the javadoc for `getParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-). There's also something else I read in some other JAX-RS/Jersey related document, but I can't seem to remember where I saw it